# Center specific mark google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I created a custom embed map on Google Maps with several points. I need to focus only one every time it is opened. I tried to center or by placing the coordinates but it still is the same.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zvxbKN4AlhTM.kknB191-MORI&z=10" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9h8fuec/

Answer (score 0):

well, the solution is add this inside de url

&z=13&ll=#latitude,#longitude

longitude= latitudinal coordinates

longitude= longitudinal coordinates

&z=13 is the zoom

should be the coordinates of the principal marker.

demo result

google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zvxbKN4AlhTM.kknB191-MORI&z=13&ll=#latitude,#longitude

The # must be eliminated. only the coordinates should be there.

Comment: The # must be eliminated. only the coordinates should be there.